# Laravel: How to get the recipient (Notifiable) from within the Notification?

Tags: laravel, notifications

I am using Laravel Notifications to broadcasts updates to the user. I am wondering if there is a way to get the Notifiable target of the notification from inside the notification itself.

```
Auth::user()->notify(
new TextNotification('Hi there!')
)
```

Now, I want to get the Notifiable instance (here is the User) inside the Notification's __construct. Does this object get passed to the notification at any point?

I know I can pass it to the notification class, but I am wondering if this is already done by Laravel.

Answer (score 3):

In this case the user is automatically inserted into the notification you're sending and you can accept it in the toArray and toMail methods.

```
// in TextNotification
public method toArray($notifiable)
{
    // $notifiable is the $user from Auth::user()
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if I can access it from the construct, say from $this

Comment: The others already answered actually. My question is why do you want to get the user instance in your Notification?

Comment: @Borisu one reason is to use the notifiable as an id in a channel to `broadcastOn()`

Answer (score 1):

yes, you get $notifiable instance in Notification class.

for more details see [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications#specifying-delivery-channels).

Comment: The notifiable is passed to ->via and ->toArray, but not available at $this (say inside the notification's instructor), right?

Comment: ... say inside the notification's __construct

Comment: @Dewan159 No, you do not get $notifiable in __construct.

Comment: Okay, this is what I was wondering about, and I think the $notifiable should be available on the notification's $this, don't you agree ?